# Does the example below violate Liskov Substitution Principal?

Tags: java, solid-principles, contract, liskov-substitution-principle

Could anybody tell me the example below violate LSP or not?

I have an example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void validate() {
        if (age == null || age < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age can not be null");
        }
    }
}
```

and the subclass:

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private String employeeCode;

    public Employee(String name, Integer age, String employeeCode) {
        super(name, age);
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        if (employeeCode == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Employee code can not be null");
        }
    }
}
```

and the main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("Person", 10);
        validate(person); // will be ok. does not throw any exception

        Person employee = new Employee("Employee", 30, null);
        validate(employee); // will be throw IllegalArgumentException because subtype's employee code is null
    }

    public static void validate(Person p) {
        p.validate();
    }
}
```

In this example the subclass add new property called `employeeCode` and override method `validate`
with additional check for it's own property `employeeCode`.

In the main method I create 2 objects. The first one is object of type `Person` and the second one is object of type `Employee`.

When validate person it is ok because all precondition is ok
but for the employee it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` because it does not match precondition

1. Does `Employee` violate LSP due to add new validation on `employeeCode`?
2. If 1 is ***yes***, how can I refactor it to avoid violate LSP?
3. If 1 is ***no***, if I change exception from `IllegalArgumentException("Employee code can not be null")` to another exception `NullPointerException`. So does it violate LSP due to introduce new exception type in subtype (which super type does not have)?

Comment: In order to answer this question we would need to know the complete contract of the `validate()` method. In languages like Java, the method signature forms only part of the [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Principle). What are the preconditions, postconditions, and invariants of this method?

Comment: @jaco0646 invariant of this method is : age must not be null or <=0. employee code can not be null.post condition is method does not throw any exception after validate

Answer (score 1):

1. No, instances of `Person` and `Employee` have exactly the same range of behaviours when `validate` is called. That is, calling it will either result in an `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown, or it won't, so no code which is calling `validate` and correctly handling the result of calling it on `Person` will fail to correctly handle the result of calling it on `Employee`.
2. n/a
3. In my opinion: As both `IllegalArgumentException` and `NullPointerException` are unchecked exceptions, they don't form part of the contract of `validate`, which is entitled to throw any subclass of `RuntimeException` it feels like. A better design would have `throws ValidationException` as part of the signature of `validate`.

As @jaco0646 says in their comment above, Java doesn't allow you to formally specify everything about a method.

Suppose I write another subclass of `Person` and decide that my `validate()` implementation will actually fix any invalid values by setting them to defaults. As we don't expect the `validate()` method to mutate the object (even though we have no formal way of saying that), that would violate LSP.

Comment: Do you mean behavior does not change for all properties that inherit from superclass (in this example age and name from Person) ?

When validating an Employee with employeeCode is null it will throw an exception
Does it called breaking the application as this article

https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle

Comment: See clarification above

Comment: "When validating an Employee with employeeCode is null it will throw an exception" as will calling validate on a `Person` with a `null` `age`. Both behave the same.